# Adding new entry to database always creating a new entry to foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I am new to Entity Framework and not able to figure out why the repository is always creating a new entry to their corresponding foreign key table?

Here is the example: in `GeoLocationType` table I have added a foreign key to `Classification` table with the name `Classification_ID`.

My models are:

```
public partial class GeoLocationType : BaseEntity
{
    public YesNoEnum? IsActive { get; set; }
    public YesNoEnum? IsAutoStoreLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual Classification classification { get; set; }
}

public partial class Classification : BaseEntity
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Now, whenever I am saving `GeoLocationType`, it's creating a new entry into `Classification` table as well.

Code:

```
if (model.Classifications_Id > 0)
{
     model.Classifications = _ClassificationRepository
                .Find(p => p.Id == model.Classifications_Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
}

var entity = Mapper.Map<GeoLocationType>(model);

Validate(entity);

_GeoLocationTypeRepository.Add(entity);
_uow.SaveChanges();
```

where `model` is a view model which has the `Classifications_Id`.

After calling the `_uow.SaveChanges();` it's creating a new entry to `Classification` table and picking it's `primary_key` to add into `GeoLocationType` table. Not sure why is this happening because `model.Classifications_Id` already exists in the `Classification` table.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attach method to attach the classification entity prior to setting it to the GeoLocationType entity

```
if (model.Classifications_Id > 0)
{
  var classification = _ClassificationRepository
     .Find(p => p.Id == model.Classifications_Id).FirstOrDefault();
  _uow.Attach(classification);
  model.Classifications = classification;
}
```

When you call _GeoLocationTypeRepository.Add(entity) in ef it will know that the classification entity already exists in db and will use it instead of creating a new one.